# Null-geodesics vs null-killing vectors

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, geodesics

Consider a null-killing vector $\xi^{\mu}$. Now due to the killing equation we have $$\nabla_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}+\nabla_{\nu}\xi_{\mu} = 0$$. Now I constract one of the index with $\xi^{\mu}$ to obtain
$$\xi^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}+\xi^{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\xi_{\mu} = \xi^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}\xi_{\nu} = 0$$ The second term vanishes in the above because $\xi^{\mu}$ is null. Now, the equation in the second equality looks like the equation for a null geodesic. I wish to know if a null-killing vector is a tangent vector to a null-geodesic and vice-versa ?

Comment: Mr. [Killing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Killing) deserves to have his name capitalized. The name of the vector has nothing to do with the verb “to kill”; it doesn’t “kill nulls” as “null-killing vector” suggests. I edited one of your previous questions that had the same problem but I’m going to let you fix this one.

Comment: @mmeent Because $\xi^{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\xi_{\mu} = \frac{1}{2}\nabla_{\nu}\xi^2 $. It was pretty obvious so I did not bother adding it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you wrote is exact, a light-like Killing vector satisfies the geodesic equation and it is the reason why **Killing horizons** (as the one of Schwarzschild-Kruskal metric) are made of null geodesics. It is however generally false that null geodsics are tangent to null Killing vectors.

Comment: So is there anything special about space-times where the tangent of null geodesics are also null-killing vectors ?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. Are you considering a spacetime such that the tangent vector  of **every** null geodesics is also a Killing vector? Yes, that is a very special spacetime: Minkowski spacetime (a portion of it).

Comment: Yes. That is what I was looking for. Thank you very much, sir.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Any maximally symmetric space would do, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ user44690  I think that   @mmeent is right. What we can conclude is that every geodesic has a Killing tangent vector, this is because with null vecotrs at a point we can generate all the tangent space at that point and linar combinations of Killing vectors are Killing vecotrs. So  there are more possibilities than Minkowski space: also maximally symmetric spaces  (e.g. de Sitter)

Comment: @user44690 I think that @ mmeent is right. What we can conclude is that every geodesic has a Killing tangent vector, this is because with null vecotrs at a point we can generate all the tangent space at that point and linar combinations of Killing vectors are Killing vecotrs. So there are more possibilities than Minkowski space: also maximally symmetric spaces (e.g. de Sitter)